# Is it common to shorten "the Shanghai Composite Index gauge" to "the Shanghai gauge" in the stock market domain?

Tags: ellipsis, terminology

> **The Shanghai gauge** dropped 1.1 percent to 2,651.79 at the close, below its January 2016 closing low. Back then, officials had just introduced and then hastily scrapped a disastrous circuit-breaker program as they grappled with one of the market’s worst-ever routs.

I think "**The Shanghai gauge**" is referring to "**the Shanghai Composite Index gauge**". (Assume my understanding is correct) Is that abbreviation common in the language of stock market?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/chinas-stocks-sink-lowest-level-070935997.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloomberg:

> "China’s sinking stock market reached an unwelcome milestone, with the
>   Shanghai Composite Index closing at the lowest level since 2014,
>   erasing the last traces of its recovery from a boom that turned into a
>   $5 trillion bust.
>
> The Shanghai gauge dropped 1.1 percent to 2,651.79, below its January
>   2016 bottom. Back then, officials had just introduced and then hastily
>   scrapped a disastrous circuit-breaker program as they grappled with
>   one of the market’s worst-ever routs."

[Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-09-17/china-s-stocks-sink-past-lowest-level-seen-in-5-trillion-crash)

They use gauge to **avoid repeating the term index or**. Acceptable terminology is: **Shanghai Composite Index, the Shanghai index or the Shanghai gauge**. A gauge means something that measures something. But you would not append gauge to: the Shanghai Composite Index.

Here is another example used for the New  York Stock Exchange (another gauge):

> TITLE in USA Today: **Dow's biggest 2-day drop since 2016 puts
>   investors on edge as stock gauge briefly falls 400 points**

[gauge](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/markets/2018/01/30/dow-falls-more-than-250-pts-extending-decline-2nd-day-after-1-900-point-early-year-rally/1078066001/)

Any measure of marketplace activity where shares or other financial instruments are traded on an exchange, including commodities, can be termed a gauge, meaning measure of the average daily volume of trading (purchase and sale of financial instruments).

Comment: So, gauge and index are interchangeable in this sense?

Comment: @dan Yes, they are.